# mouseover for markerclusterer object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am using marketclusterer object (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js) for grouping multiple markers in one cluster when the map is zoomed out.

Now I have an infobox which is shown when that marker cluster is clicked. I am doing that by this chunk of code:

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(markerCluster, 'clusterclick', function (cluster) {
            var content;
            var markers2 = cluster.getMarkers();
            for(var i=0;i<markers2.length;i++)
            {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title,
                    description: data.description,
                    companyname: data.companyname,
                    logofilename: data.logofilename,
                    postingid: data.postingid,
                    jobtitle: markers2[i].jobtitle
                }); 
                var testt = markers2[i].companyname;                    
                content += '<IMG BORDER="0" width="80" height="50" style="margin-right:5px;" ALIGN="Left" SRC='+ decodeURIComponent(markers[i].logofilename)+'>'+markers[i].companyname+'<br /> ' + '<a href='+'javascript:NewWindow('+"'"+'../JobSeeker/JobPostingApplication.aspx?PostingID='+markers[i].postingid+'&GetPosting=True'+"'"+')>' + markers[i].jobtitle+'</a><br /><br /> ';
            }                       
            infoWindow.setContent('<div style="width:210px;height:150px;">'+content+'</div>');
           
            var latLng = cluster.getCenter();
            //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(cluster.getCenter().ya, cluster.getCenter().za);               
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latLng.ob, latLng.pb);
            infoWindow.setPosition(myLatlng);
            infoWindow.open(map);
        });
```

I want to achieve the same thing with 'mouseover', but I tried both 'mouseover' and "mouseover" but nothing happens and no JS error is shown in the console.

Do I need to call some other event for showing the infobox when the mouse is over the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [MarkerClusterPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html) (per the documentation, it supports mouseover events ([MarkerClusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/reference.html) doesn't mention events).